# How to use tfs build definition to run custom msbuild file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs, msbuild

I have create a custom msbuild file and name it "a.msbuild" which contains a CustomTarget.

I can run it via VS command prompt with follow command:

```
msbuild "a.msbuild" /t:CustomTarget /p:sampleParameter='abc'
```

Now, I want to use tfs Build Definition get the same result with above command. How can I config it?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using and why did you choose MSbuild? MSbuild scripts are not the preferred way to go about building applications in TFS anymore, and haven't been the preferred way for about 5 years.

Comment: Whats the '.msbuild'  flie ? Did you mean the '.proj' or '.csproj' file like this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms400767(v=vs.90).aspx mentioned?

Comment: '.msbuild' is just like a '.csproj'. It contains custom code to build our project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you need to use msbuild file in TFS2012. Usually,this is used in TFS2005 or TFS2008. The only situation you need to use it in TFS2012 is that your TFS server upgradted from TFS2005 or TFS2008.

For TFS2012, we use process template. Details from MSDN:  [Customize your build process template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647551(v=vs.120).aspx)